# regular expression on replace method of js not working

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

why this is not working

```
var value = arr[row][col].replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'),'""');
```

**Error :** Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:22:01 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1041
Char: 25
Code: 0
URI: http://example.com/?

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1041
Char: 25
Code: 0
URI: http://example.com/?

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1041
Char: 25
Code: 0
URI: http://example.com/?

**Note:** : Error copied directly from debugger of IE8

Comment: ... And what's in arr at those indices? Ask a complete question.

Comment: Sir, It contains string value.

Comment: @user950146 `''` is a string value.

Comment: In these sorts of examples, its useful to replicate it in http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can help debug a little better

Comment: What do you see in the console if you enter `arr[row][col].valueOf()`?

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons: you're not replacing occurrences of a substring, but trying to use string manipulation methods on a DOM-Element. Better do something like this:

```
var value = arr[row][col].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'),'""');
```

But I'm really not a fan of regex in this case (I love Regex, but only when needed). I'd replace all `"` with `""` like so:

```
var value = arr[row][col].innerHTML.split('"').join('""');
```

Faster, easier to read, and gives you the same result. Though 1 thing to keep in mind: if the source string already contains double quotes (`""`), these will be quadrupled. If this is a possible scenario, you do need a regex like this:

```
var value = arr[row][col].innerHTML.replace(/(?:[^"]"(?:[^"]))/g,'""');
```

This will only match quotes that are neither preceded by a quote nor followed by one... Pick any of the above solutions, but remember: if you chose to use the first option, studies have shown you're 50% more likely to have less friends ;-).

Comment: Thnx Elias for trying to help me. I think i detected the problem. Somehow, An object was being passed as a value in loop of string values. I used the "typeof" keyword to filter such objects and now it is working.

Comment: I disagree with the readability statement, because it is a hack that obscures the intent of the code. Also, I can't produce a test case where the .split is consistently faster. I'd go for `var r = /"/g; ..loop.. { t.replace(r, '""'); }`.

Comment: Further testing indicates that `..loop.. { t.replace(/"/g, '""'); }` will be the most performant way to do this. Apparently, browser JS engines are rather smart these days :).

Comment: @user950146: your explanation leads me to believe you're actually using a `for - in` loop, this will pass methods, prototype values, as well as the actual properties, for arrays, you're better of using the `for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)` loop. @Bergius: readability is a matter of habit and preference, so I can't really argue with you there. Faster: there is a negligible difference, but I haven't tested this thoroughly. But as a general rule, I try to avoid regex if possible. Good suggestion of constructing the regex outside the loop btw, user950146: create regex outside loop!

Comment: browser JS engines are rather smart these days <= tested on v8, or FF, probably :). joking aside: you could very well be right: JS deals with regex differently than a lot of other languages (ie: doesn't treat it like string).

Comment: Indeed. All bets are off if one needs/wants to care about the broken browsers. I did think that creating the regex outside of the loop would be smart, but FF proved me wrong – regex literal inside the loop was a massive improvement compared to both split/join and moving regex creation out of the loop. So, @user950146, regex literal inside the loop if you're dealing with a non-trivial amount of data :).

Comment: good to know! You would expect constructing the regex once would be faster, but as you said JS engines are smarter than you'd think...